Run All Tests в Android Studio запускает не все тесты
Пытаюсь запустить UI-тесты на Kaspresso в Android Studio через Run All Tests:

Раньше это запускало все UI-тесты, которые есть в проекте. Сейчас же, каждый раз запускается разное количество тестов, всегда меньшее, чем есть на самом деле.

Invalidate caches &  restart не помогает
ребилд не помогает
переустанавливала уже все, что только можно
в config run-а все так же, как и у коллег, но у них такой проблемы нет:


Проблема возникла сама по себе из ниоткуда, так как никаких настроек я не трогала. Запускать пробую на разных устройствах - итог одинаковый.
версия AGP - 8.6.1,
Android Studio - Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 2,
ОС - Win 10
